# Is it possible to find the process causing a traps msg in dmesg?

Tags: linux, dmesg

I am trying to troubleshoot a message that floods dmesg:

```
[Tue Mar  5 20:46:23 2019] traps: g16[7254] trap invalid opcode ip:404956 sp:7fff6d7c6200 error:0 in g16[400000+4cf7000]
[Tue Mar  5 20:46:24 2019] traps: g16[7356] trap invalid opcode ip:404956 sp:7fff1fa4bad0 error:0 in g16[400000+4cf7000]
[Tue Mar  5 20:46:24 2019] traps: g16[7375] trap invalid opcode ip:404956 sp:7fff2a3f6b50 error:0 in g16[400000+4cf7000]
[Tue Mar  5 22:31:21 2019] traps: g16[26561] trap invalid opcode ip:404956 sp:7ffca1ae89d0 error:0 in g16[400000+4cf7000]
[Tue Mar  5 22:35:10 2019] traps: g16[26801] trap invalid opcode ip:404956 sp:7ffe0542aad0 error:0 in g16[400000+4cf7000]
```

This is linux:

```
bash-4.2$ uname -a
Linux cx1-138-5-1 3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 1 14:54:57 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This happens continuously, at some interval. Is there any way to identify which program it may be, eg. from the `ip:404956` which seems to always be the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process is clearly showed in that output (g16 with pid 7254 etc). The ip and sp are the instruction pointer and stack pointer registers.

Error 0 if you look [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/include/asm/traps.h#n148): is the divide by 0 error.

Comment: Great! Is there a document somewhere that explpains the meaning of g16 and its siblings?

Comment: And another thing: is it possible to suppress these messages? I know it is not normally something one wants to do, but these are student systems, and it is not important (to me) that they keep making program errors and don't bother to fix them.

Comment: g16 would be the name of binary, not a well known process. As for disabling those you should look at: https://superuser.com/questions/351387/how-to-stop-kernel-messages-from-flooding-my-console